# All UK census geographies in one file irrespective of scale

Tags: data, census, united-kingdom

Is it possible to get all UK census geographies in one file?

For example, I am currently looking at a table of data titled

```
Life satisfaction by country, region, unitary authority and county, April 2011 to March 2012
```

Which turns out to mean unitary authorities or counties, or local authorities in Scotland.  Nevertheless each entry has its own code (e.g. `E06000006`).  Is there a single shapefile that will match all of these without having to download all the geographies separately?

Answer (score 1):

I have previously downloaded the data from [this site](http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-feb-2013/Census/?webSyncID=989a67fd-12bd-4670-96e8-3e615c75144d&vs=YWM2MjYwMTYtNjJjZC00MWYxLWIzYTktOTgxNTJjNmM1OGQyOzsS1) which is run by the people behind MapInfo. It currently only has England and Wales, but hopefully that still save you a bit of time if you want the entire UK.

You should then be able to join your data table to this spatial dataset using Output Area code.